# How to remotely debug SQL from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

Since debugging was removed from SSMS, I have been unable to get Visual Studio to successfully debug SQL queries.

I am able to connect to the database fine and execute sql statements, but when executing the debugger, I get two errors:

[image: Unable to access the SQL Server debugging interface. DCOM]

[image: Unable to start program SQL Server sys/=0]

- I have enabled TCP ports **135** and IPsec UDP ports **4500** & **500** of remote firewall.
- SSDT is installed.
- Debugging in SSMS 17 still works without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try these suggestions；

**1)** disable **Use Managed Compatibility Mode** option and **Enable native Edit and Continue** option under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**

**2)** After that, restart the two pcs and then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although this is already my configuration.

Comment: Did you have the administrator right to access the sql sever on the remote pc? You should contact with your administrator for the right permission. And then on your current pc, start VS with Admin. Besides, did you refer to [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) to install the related workload and vsix? Also,[configure firewall rules before running the TSQL Debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/configure-firewall-rules-before-running-the-tsql-debugger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).