# Need detailed instructions for debugging SQL Server stored procedure in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2019

I am a victim of the debugger having been removed in SSMS v18. You are now supposed to do it in Visual Studio 2019, but I am failing. I have read many webpages on the subject. For example:

[Why aren't my breakpoints hitting SQL In Visual Studio 2019 debugging script from network server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536549/why-arent-my-breakpoints-hitting-sql-in-visual-studio-2019-debugging-script-fro)

[How to: Debug a SQL Server CLR Integration stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms165051(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[How to debug SQL from Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473815/how-to-debug-sql-from-visual-studio-2019)

What I try: here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DevTest]
AS
    DECLARE @dHrs decimal(12,4)

    SELECT @dHrs = dbo.TNPF_OperHours(592,'2020/10/31 23:59 -07:00')

    RETURN @dHrs
```

Its purpose is to test function `dbo.TNPF_OperHours`.

I set a breakpoint on the SELECT statement. From the SQL main menu item I click on 'Execute With Debugger'. The entire procedure is highlighted in yellow; the breakpoint disappears. I cannot set a breakpoint. I press F11. The yellow highlighted procedure disappears and I am back at the editing window with the breakpoint highlighted.

I thought maybe I need a SQL project in the solution. After creating one I could not find a way of debugging from there.

My development environment is a single Win 10 computer with this SQL Server installation:

[image: SQL Server Installation]

I use Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I develop websites for tiny non-profit organizations. I am retired and I donate my time. And I am stuck and would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The above is never going to work as you expect either. `RETURN` is to the success status of a procedure, and it returns an `int`. You're trying to `RETURN` a `decimal(12,4)` here, which will be implicitly be converted to an `int`. Why do you need to proc anyway, when you can just call the scalar function? There's no need to have a proc  to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the latest SSMS v.17.9.1 that supports inline debugging.
It can coexist with SSMS 18.* on the same machine.

[SSMS 17.9.1 download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#1791)

Comment: Yitzhak - yes, thank you, tried that already. SSMS 17.9.1 malfunctioned and I gave up. Maybe I should just uninstall and reinstall.